# Entity Splitting with Code Only

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, code-first

Is their a way using Entity Framework Code-Only to have an entity that has fields from two tables if both tables don't contain the primary key?

Here is an example.

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public int PostID { get; set; }
    public String PostBody { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public String Username { get; set; }
}

public class BlogPostConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<BlogPost>
{
    public BlogPostConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(b => b.PostID);
    }
}

public class UserConfiguration : EntityConfiguration<User>
{
    public UserConfiguration()
    {
        HasKey(b => b.UserID);
    }
}
```

I want the Username property of the BlogPost object to be mapped to the username column of the User table.  I can do the mapping using a foreign key using the designer but I'm not sure how to do that using Code Only.  I tried using two MapHierarchy statements in my configuration object but it looks like that only works if both tables us the same primary key.

Comment: have you seen this 
http://microsoftpdc.com/Sessions/FT10 demo about EF from pdc09?
if not - take a look at it.

Comment: Thanks Alexander, that video was great but unfortunately it didn't address Entity Splitting.   Highly recommended watch though for anyone getting into EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible with the current state of Entity Framework.

In order to do entity splitting you have to have a 1-to-1 mapping (the primary key must be in both tables).

I was incorrect with my questing in assuming that because you can add columns from a second table in the designer that the code will actually work.  I get a very similar error when trying to do the mapping in the EDMX as I do when using Code-Only.